# What is the client behavior for declined updates in WSUS?

Tags: wsus, windows-update

When I decline a particular update in WSUS, my understanding is that means the WSUS server will stop offering that particular update.

However, does the Windows Update client continue to display that it needs that particular update, but just never install it? Or do the updates get moved to the "Optional" category in Windows Update? Or, are they simply not displayed?

Basically I'm interested in what the Windows Update client displays in regards to declined updates, so I can communicate to sysadmins on our network what they should expect to see if they decide to manually check for updates.

Comment: If you decline an update, it won’t show up on the client, unless you search online for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I decline a particular update in WSUS, my understanding is that
>   means the WSUS server will stop offering that particular update.

TRUE. WSUS Server stops offering the declined update(s) to clients, neither for evaluation nor for installation.

> However, does the Windows Update client continue to display that it
>   needs that particular update, but just never install it?  Or do the updates 
>   get moved to the "Optional" category in Windows Update? Or, are they simply 
>   not displayed?

As I stated above, the Windows Update client won't be able to find the update. It'd be as if the declined update was never there. So, the client system can't evaluate the update after decline of the same.

There is also the option of UnApproving an update, and Approval for Removal of an update, instead of directly declining. You can further explore about these topics on [WSUS - Managing the Updates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708474(v=ws.10).aspx).

> Basically I'm interested in what the Windows Update client displays in
>   regards to declined updates, so I can communicate to sysadmins on our
>   network what they should expect to see if they decide to manually
>   check for updates.

Again, as I stated, Windows Update client won't be displaying the declined update for installation in client system. The declined updates will be only stored in the list of declined updates in the WSUS Server. Client systems won't be able to find these set of declined updates (as if they were never there).